# Cannot control fan in ubuntu 13.10 thinkpad edge e531

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fan

I am having trouble with my fan on my Lenovo thinkpad laptop. I have installed lm-sensors and ran sensors-detect and also added option fan_control=1 as a module parameter. The issue is two-fold.

First, I don't think my fan is detected at all. The reasons:

- running `sensors` gives the following output:

  ```
  acpitz-virtual-0
  Adapter: Virtual device
  temp1:        +29.8°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

  coretemp-isa-0000
  Adapter: ISA adapter
  Physical id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
  Core 0:         +41.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
  Core 1:         +38.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

  thinkpad-isa-0000
  Adapter: ISA adapter
  fan1:           0 RPM

  pkg-temp-0-virtual-0
  Adapter: Virtual device
  temp1:        +41.0°C
  ```

As you can see fan1 = 0 RPM (this **never** changes)

- running `cat /proc/acpi/ibm/fan` gives the following output:

  ```
  status:     enabled
  speed:      0
  level:      auto
  commands:   level <level> (<level> is 0-7, auto, disengaged, full-speed)
  commands:   enable, disable
  commands:   watchdog <timeout> (<timeout> is 0 (off), 1-120 (seconds))
  ```

"Speed" is **always** 0.

- trying to manually change the level of /proc/acpi/ibm/fan does not have any effect. Level 0 and Level 7 are basically the same.

Secondly, if I assume that my fan is detected (and control works), there is the problem that once it starts running - it never stops (even when temps are low). I tried installing thinkfan, controlfan and other apps, but it still doesn't change anything.

I would like to point out that I have a hybrid GPU system, but I am using bumbleebe, so I only use the nvidia card when I run `optirun <app>`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Confirming issue on ThinkPad Edge E520 with Ubuntu 14.04. However, the fan works as expected when dual-booted to Windows 7.

Comment: what happens when you run it fullspeed?

Comment: Have you checked for a BIOS update and whether the chipset driver is the right one for the computer?

Comment: Same issue here. E530 + Ubuntu 14.04. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily may work here, but when I worked for DELL, most of the issues like that was solved installing OMSA package.
It then caused Linux to miraculously find AGAIN hardware that was there before update, but missing after.

So my suggestion would be to look for something related to overall hardware detection problems on vendor site?

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar problem and I solved it by:

```
# modprobe thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

After doing that. What happens when you:

```
# echo "level full-speed" > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

I am using thinkfan in a Lenovo Thinkpad x201 and it works fine.